# If you have a Liquibase changeset which uses <sqlfile> and you change the file it references

Tags: liquibase

Is a new checksum calculated?

Thank you,

Tim

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the checksum is based on the sqlfile contents, so changes to the file will affect the checksum.